# Securely store password hash django

Tags: django, authentication, passwords, password-protection

Currently my application is properly storing the password upon submit, but it isn't hashed and is being stored in plaintext.

My view:

```
def Registration(request):
    RegForm = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if RegForm.is_valid():
            clearUserName = RegForm.cleaned_data['userNm']   
            clearPassNoHash = RegForm.cleaned_data['userPass']
            clearPass = bcrypt.hashpw(clearPassNoHash.encode("utf-8"), bcrypt.gensalt(14) )
            RegForm.save()
            try:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/Newuser/?userNm=' + clearUserName)
            except:
                raise ValidationError(('Invalid request'), code='300')    
    else:
        RegForm = RegistrationForm()

        return render(request, 'VA/reuse/register.html', {
            'RegForm': RegForm 
        })
```

**form**

```
class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    userPass = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label='Password')
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['userNm','userPass']
```

**models.py**

```
class Client(models.Model):
    userNm = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Email",max_length=50,unique=True) #userNm = <user's email>
    userPass = models.CharField(verbose_name="Password", max_length=50)
```

The problem is with `clearPass` in the view it seems where it is just sending the value of `clearPassNoHash` since its value is part of the `.cleaned_data[]` . Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'd appreciate some help on properly implementing this in order to hash the pass.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just assigning values to variables. You should be assigning it to the form:

```
    if RegForm.is_valid():
        clearUserName = RegForm.cleaned_data['userNm']   
        clearPassNoHash = RegForm.cleaned_data['userPass']
        RegForm.userPass = bcrypt.hashpw(clearPassNoHash.encode("utf-8"), bcrypt.gensalt(14) )
        RegForm.save()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this - it submits form, but the form contains unhashed, plaintext password. I also tried: `userPassHashed = bcrypt.hashpw(RegForm.cleaned_data['userPass'].encode("utf-8"), bcrypt.gensalt(14) ) `   but that didnt work either. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My solution was to define a method in my models.py and call the method to hash my plain text password. Here's my code:

```
#models.py
def hash_password(password):
#since our user model is from AbstractBaseUser, we need to manually hash passwords
    hashed = make_password(password) #returns PBKDF2 hashed password
    return hashed

#views.py
#encrypt plain password            
form.instance.password = hash_password(clean['password'])
```

You don't have to use this(PBKDF2) hashing algorithm, you can use which ever one you want (e.g. your Bcrypt algorithm). As long as you return the hashed value you should be good. A second solution you could use is the built in [set_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) but I personally have never used it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and found that instantiating the new user before committing fixed the problem for me:

```
def Registration(request):
    RegForm = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if RegForm.is_valid():
            new_user = RegForm.save(commit=False)
            new_user.userNm = RegForm.cleaned_data['userNm']   
            new_user.userPass = bcrypt.hashpw(
                RegForm.cleaned_data['userPass'].encode("utf-8"), 
                bcrypt.gensalt(14))
            new_user.save()
            try:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/Newuser/?userNm=' + clearUserName)
            except:
                raise ValidationError(('Invalid request'), code='300')    
    else:
        RegForm = RegistrationForm()

        return render(request, 'VA/reuse/register.html', {
            'RegForm': RegForm 
        })
```